# spark -- Kafka streaming Exception -- object not serializableConsumerRecord

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I am running a kafka stream reader on spark

Following are dependencies

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

When some data say 'Hi----3' is produced to kafka topic, Getting the following exception (I can see the data though in exception) --

```
Serialization stack:
- object not serializable (class: org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord, value: ConsumerRecord(topic = q_metrics, partition = 0, offset = 26, CreateTime = 1480588636828, checksum = 3939660770, serialized key size = -1, serialized value size = 9, key = null, value = "Hi----3"))
```

I am not doing any computation on rdd (as that was also throwing same exception). Even stream.print() is also throwing the exception

Following is the code

```
import org.apache.spark.streaming._
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010._
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.LocationStrategies.PreferConsistent
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.Subscribe
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.ConsumerStrategies.Subscribe
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD

class Metrics {

  def readKafka() {
    val kafkaParams = Map[String, Object](
      "bootstrap.servers" -> "localhost:9092",
      "key.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
      "value.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
      "group.id" -> "use_a_separate_group_id_for_each_stream",
      "auto.offset.reset" -> "latest",
      "enable.auto.commit" -> (false: java.lang.Boolean))

    val topics = Array("q_metrics")
    val sc = new SparkContext("local[4]", "ScalaKafkaConsumer")
    val streamingContext = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(10))

    val stream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String](
                            streamingContext,
                            PreferConsistent,
                            Subscribe[String, String](topics, kafkaParams))

    stream.print()


    streamingContext.start

    streamingContext.awaitTermination()

  }

  def rddReader(rdd: Array[String]) = {

  }
}

object MetricsReader {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val objMetrics = new Metrics()
    objMetrics.readKafka()
  }
}
```

Appreciate any help.

Thanks

Comment: Are you able to receive the message on kafka consumer console?

Comment: no. I see that message as part of that exception.

Comment: I think you need to add some jars to your kafka/lib location like metrics-core and kafka-clients if not there.

Comment: Can you provide the list of your kafka/lib jars list?

Comment: both metrics-core-3.1.2.jar,  kafka-clients-0.10.0.1.jar are there in classpath....cant past the whole set, as it is huge

Comment: in kafka lib -- metrics-core-2.2.0.jar, kafka-clients-0.10.0.0.jar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the issue, we cannot print directly as 'print' calls the ConsumerRecord. So I used map to get the record , *collected* the key value then printed

```
stream.foreachRDD { rdd => 
                        val collected = rdd.map(record => ( record.key(), record.value() )).collect()
                        for ( c <- collected )  {
                           println(c)
                        }
                  }
```